# iOS - How to marge audio record on my Camera Session?

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to add record audio when I record video Session. I want to helping me how to make syntax or where to add my audio device and where to combine the files.

```
func setupCameraSession() {

    // setup video device input
    let videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVCaptureDeviceInput instance with error: \(error).")
    }
    guard cameraSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    cameraSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

    // setup video output
    self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    self.videoDataOutput?.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) ]
    let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videocapturequeue", attributes: [])
    self.videoDataOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    self.videoDataOutput?.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    if self.cameraSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput!) {
        self.cameraSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput!)
    }
    do {
        try self.currentDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
        self.currentDevice?.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, fpsValue) // 20 fps
        self.currentDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("could not configure a device")
        return
    }
    self.cameraSession.startRunning()
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, we stuck on this also.. Did you solved it?

Comment: unfortunately, still unsolved :(